# Is there a LateX addon that directly let's me type in LateX into blender?

Tags: mathematics

Is there a LateX add-on that directly lets me type in LateX into blender ?

If not, is there a Python code for this to directly type into blender using this code ?

Just to be clear, I would like to type in equation (math mode)

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting the question I found this addon that works well

https://github.com/ghseeli/latex2blender/wiki